# JSON response undefined: using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, json, get, xmlhttprequest

I am using XMLHTTPRequest to get a JSON response. When I view the Response tab in Firebug, it shows me the JSON object, which I have validated on [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com).  When I try to access the object's properties, I get

> TypeError: obj is undefined

I have researched for several hours, but have not been able to find a working solution.

Code:

```
function getState(light) {
  var txt = execute('GET', 'http://' + bridge + '/api/' + hash + '/lights/' + light);
  var obj = eval('(' + txt + ')');
  //var obj = JSON.parse(txt);
  //this gives me "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character"
  console.log(obj.name);
}

function execute($method, $url, $message) { //used for both PUT and GET requests
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open($method, $url, true)
  xmlhttp.send($message);
  console.log(xmlhttp.response);
  return xmlhttp.response;
}
```

In the Firebug Response tab, it indicates response of GET request:   200 OK -4ms

```
{
  "state": {
    "on": false,
    "bri": 200,
    "hue": 8664,
    "sat": 140,
    "xy": [0.4932, 0.3832],
    "ct": 428,
    "alert": "none",
    "effect": "none",
    "colormode": "hs",
    "reachable": true
  },
  "type": "Extended color light",
  "name": "Left rear living room 1",
  "modelid": "LCT001",
  "swversion": "65003148",
  "pointsymbol": {
    "1": "none",
    "2": "none",
    "3": "none",
    "4": "none",
    "5": "none",
    "6": "none",
    "7": "none",
    "8": "none"
  }
}
```

When I call my getState function (on pageload), the console.log claims that xmlhttp.response is an empty string.   Doing typeof on 'txt' and 'obj' returns undefined.   I'm trying to access the object elements, such as:

`obj.name` and `obj.state.on`

I am new to using JSON and XMLHttpRequest - my code is based on a template someone else had initially created.  I have no problem with PUT requests I used elsewhere in my program, using the above functions, but cannot seem to get GET requests working.

Please let me know if I left out any important info.  Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: is 'bridge' (servername) the same or a different machinename (and port) ?

Comment: I stopped reading after `eval(`. Sigh...

Comment: The first A in AJAX stands for **asynchronous**

Comment: @Pointy: You're the first one here to mention AJAX :P

Comment: To clarify AlienWebguy's comment: please use a JSON parsing library (or the built-in `JSON.prase` function in most modern browsers) for parsing network-received JSON: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html#security-considerations

Comment: I suggest to read a good introduction to [XMLHttpRequest API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). It can clarify the reason why your code doesn't works as expected.

Comment: @AlienWebguy and Apsillers: the line after eval(   shows that I also tried JSON.parse, but it returned an error, and I could not figure out why.

Comment: @Pointy:  I am not using AJAX

Comment: @user2234193 You're using XMLHttpRequest, which is the prime ingredient in "ajax". It doesn't matter that you're not using XML.  Your response will not be ready until the HTTP request completes, but the call to `.send()` returns immediately.

Comment: @Pointy: thanks for the clarification -- I'm obviously new to all this!

Comment: @user2234193 If `JSON.parse` fails, it's because it is getting malformed input. In this case, you're feeding it `undefined`, which is getting coerced into the string `"undefined"`. You can reproduce this for yourself by running `JSON.parse("undefined")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML HTTP request is set to be asynchronous (i.e. the script doesn't wait until the response is received and continues while the HTTP request is happening in the background).

This means that there is not enough time for there to be an `xmlhttp.response` before you return it. As a consequence, `txt` is undefined so `obj` is undefined, just as the error message said.

Change the `xmlhttp.open` call so that the call is synchronous (i.e. the script waits until the HTTP response is received before continuing):

```
xmlhttp.open($method, $url, false); // true => asynchronous, false => synchronous
```

Comment: It's probably good to keep in mind that in most circumstances, synchronous requests are generally thought to be a really bad idea for usability reasons, because the browser window will be frozen until the request completes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  For my particular application, I think I actually want the browser to wait for the request to complete.