# JSON without jQuery

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

Using a version of the example from [youmightnotneedjquery.com](//youmightnotneedjquery.com), I'm trying to get JSON into my page that is stored in the same folder as the HTML and JS. My problem is I'm not familiar with the XMLHttpRequest library and the answer I keep finding is "use jQuery or some other library." I added a `console.log();` to the function so I could see if I was reaching success or failure because I'm not getting the data back. The original example is [here](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#json) and my code is below. The cv.json exists, is formatted correctly, and the function is sending `Success?` to the console, but I can't get the JSON data into my `cv` variable.

In case it is relevant, I'm hosting the JSON, HTML, and JS files in a public dropbox folder which doesn't seem to be part of the problem.

```
   var cv;

  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'cv.json', true);

  request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400){
      // Success!
      console.log("Success?");
      console.log(request.resonseText);
      cv = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    } else {
      // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
      console.log("Error?");
    }
  };

  request.onerror = function() {
    // There was a connection error of some sort
  };

  request.send();
```

**Note:** There are lots of *similar* questions on stackoverflow but I haven't been able to find an answer to the specific issue I'm encountering; perhaps for people familiar with JavaScript this answer is too obvious to mention explicitly or I'm phrasing my searches incorrectly.

**UPDATE:** In the web inspector I can see the json file in the sources, with a response 200 *and* all the data so the file is accessible and being read, I'm just not getting it into the variable correctly apparently. Code updated to reflect corrected use of `request.send();`.

Comment: Where is that `cv.json` file located at? Is it in the same folder as your script?

Comment: do a `console.log(request.resonseText)` to see if you actually get the right data.

Comment: It returned `undefined` so I tried changing the URL to the full URL of the file instead of the relative one and it still returns `undefined`. Thanks for pointing out that obvious troubleshooting step though, I should have thought of that.

Comment: This is starting to look like a scoping problem maybe? If I put the code directly into the console it _works_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The two issues that were preventing the JSON from being show on the page, but still available from the console were

- Not loading the variable correctly (resolved thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22791925/1007711))
- <del>Loading the file *asynchronously!* (resolved thanks to [this similar question and it's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15774310/1007711))</del>
- Thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791721/json-without-jquery#comment34767109_22795763), I went out and started my journey of learning about callbacks. The JSON load is now a function made as a callback. It's not optimized I'm sure, but sufficient for my current needs/abilities

Here is the working code. <del>The significant change is the `false` on line 3.</del>

```
var cv;

var loadJSON = function() {
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'cv.json', true);

  request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400){
      cv = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    } else {
      // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
    }
  };

  request.onerror = function() {
    // There was a connection error of some sort
  };

  request.send();
};
```

Comment: The code above works for the reasons I laid out but there is disagreement on this answer. If this is poorly formatted, wrong information, or bad practice let me know. :-)

Comment: In general you should never use *synchronous* HTTP requests. You need to change the architecture of your application to work with asynchronous functions.

Answer (score 2):

request.send does not return anything, it creates a handler that resolves a value. at the top level of this add:

```
var cv;
```

and then in the success part of the onload function change your return to:

```
cv = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
```

Comment: Still returns `undefined`. I thought maybe the SSL on dropbox was interfering, but you can load public files on http and that didn't make any difference either.

Comment: a value will not be defined until the request is resolved and it is assigned the value of JSON.parse. it will not happen in line. Either call the function with cv at the point it is resolved (in the success function) or setup an event system to resolve it on change

Comment: I got it to work by making it load the JSON in synchronously instead of asynchronously.